# 11 Teams, 3 Medals, How many Combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

If the soccer league has 11 teams, assuming there are no tied records, how many possible ways are there for the gold, silver, and bronze medals to be awarded to the top three teams at the end of the season?

I'm not too sure what I'm supposed to do with this. I thought about do !11=11*10*9...etc. That didn't work.

What do the different medals have to do with it? Do I have to do !11 for every medal?

Comment: Could you please include your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Put in simple terms there are $11\cdot 10 \cdot 9$ posibilities

Comment: Terrible question. I think only one way. The first place should have gold, second silver, third bronze. Apart from that, I think @JJR comment is better than the given answers, since I don't think nr. 4..11 should be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$\color{blue}{\binom{11}{3}}\times\color{red}{3!}=990.$$

**Explanation:**

- In blue is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) of $11$ by $3$: it tells us in how many different ways we can choose $3$ teams out of the $11$.
- In red is the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) of $3$: it tells us in how many ways we can arrange the three leading teams on the podium.
- For each set of $3$ winning teams we **multiply** by the number of possible orderings of the three leading teams. This is how we arrived at the provided answer.

Comment: If we multiply $\binom{11}{3}$ by $3!$, we obtain $165 \cdot 6 = 990$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My mistake, I must have gotten the order of operations wrong when I typed it into Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 1):

By the definition [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}k$ is a number of ways we are able to select $k$ elements from $n$. If we already have $k$ elements then we have $k!$ ways to rearrange them.

So the answer is $\binom{11}3 \cdot 3! = 990$.

Comment: 11 choose 3 = 165, how did you arrive to 45760?